# Can we get the styling for the pagination on Winter Bash leaderboard pages back?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, pagination, winter-bash-2020

This year's [Winter Bash leaderboard pages](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) do not have any styling for the pagination:

[image]

However, in past Winter Bashes, the pagination buttons look much nicer, **and most importantly, more user-friendly and easier to click on**.

**2017**

[image]

**2018 / 19**

[image]

### Can we please get the styling for the buttons back so that the pagination will look like this:

[image]

---

If it makes it easier, I have attached the CSS code for the pagination buttons (taken from a past Winter Bash) below:

```
.pager, .page-sizer {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.page-numbers {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #dde;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 6px 9px;
    border: 1px solid #dde;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-radius:15px
}

.page-numbers.desc {
    border:none
}

.page-numbers:hover {
    text-decoration:none
}

.page-numbers.current {
    font-weight:bold
}

.page-numbers.dots, .page-numbers.desc {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow:none
}

.page-numbers.dots:hover, .page-numbers.desc:hover {
    background: transparent;
    color:#dde
}

.page-numbers.dots:active, .page-numbers.desc:active {
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    padding:6px 9px
}

.page-numbers:active {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    color: #999;
    text-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    padding:7px 10px
}

.page-numbers:hover {
    color: #444;
    background:#f3f3f3
}

.page-numbers.current {
    background-color: #54587a;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    padding:7px 10px
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page numbers now have styles very close to what you suggested.

> want to see moar page?
> pager format makes you sad?
> how `bout them apples?